# HTML5 support information

Tags: javascript, html

I have been facing difficult time finding which browsers support which HTML 5 API and which not.

Is there a website where i can get information like which browsers supports(have implemented) which HTML5 API(file, canvas, geolocation ......) and which are not yet supported ........ at one place.

Yes, i would like to get information for the individual api...... functions, properties like Blob in the File API

[TEST YOUR BROWSER](http://www.html5test.com/) this one is good but this need to be run for each browsers and individual browsers version and there support is hard to find especially when we have only one version of that browsers installed on our machine. Hopefully some one must have collected this information before this per browsers per version basis.

I would like to target Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, IE, Safari ........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one may be what you are looking for : http://caniuse.com/